# Updating a database with keeping relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a database which has some tables I want to keep up-to-date. I've got to write a SQL script that checks if there are certain rows in target tables and if there are not, insert them. I tried `MERGE`, but i have **8** tables related to the **9th** one so there are **8** foreign keys and I don't know how to update them all. I don't want to delete all and insert again, because i want to save my main table rows' IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use trigger that automatically add inserted rows to destination tables